# Angular Kendo Charts horizontal scrollbar

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-chart, kendo-template, kendo-angular-ui

I would like to add a horizontal scrollbar so that I can clearly view all the graph data.

for example:
if I had all 12 months of the year I would like to see those of 2019 and then with the scroll bar go to 2020 and 2021.
through the parameter that identifies the X axis.

```
<kendo-chart (seriesClick)="onSeriesClick($event)">
  <kendo-chart-title text="title"></kendo-chart-title>
  <kendo-chart-category-axis>
    <kendo-chart-category-axis-item
                  [categories]="month"
                  [title]="{ text: 'Months' }">
    </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
  </kendo-chart-category-axis>
  <kendo-chart-legend position="bottom" [visible]="false"></kendo-chart-legend>
  <kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-series-item type="line" 
                  [style]="normal" categoryField="month" 
                  [data]="Totaldata" field="total" 
                  [markers]="{ visible: true }">
   </kendo-chart-series-item>
 </kendo-chart-series>
```

[image]

Regards,